# How can I reduce draw calls when using glBufferSubData and DYNAMIC_DRAW?

Tags: opengl, rendering, opengl-es, webgl

At first I had the problem where I had about 150 rectangles rendered every tick. I only used `STATIC_DRAW` and `glBufferData`. I added support for `DYNAMIC_DRAW` and `glBufferSubData` and now I have a very good result... but the number of draw calls (`glDrawArrays`) is the same. Best practices from Mozilla Dev website said it should be reduced, but how?

Every rectangle has a method `render()` in which I do following (shortend):

```
_gl.bindBuffer(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
_gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_position);
_gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_position, 2, WebGL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
_gl.bufferSubData(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices);

_gl.bindBuffer(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, texCoordBuffer);     
_gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_texCoordLocation);
_gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_texCoordLocation, 2, WebGL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
_gl.bufferSubData(WebGL.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, texVertices);

_gl.uniform2fv(_utranslation, _translation);
_gl.uniform2fv(_urotation, _rotation);
_gl.uniform2f(_location, Dart2D.WIDTH, Dart2D.HEIGHT);

_gl.drawArrays(WebGL.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

So every rectangle calls `drawArrays` in every frame...

Comment: How many draw calls do you make now? How do you organize your data in buffers now? In general the answer to "how do I reduce the number of draw calls" is "by organizing your data so you can make fewer draw calls," but that's not a very good question/answer for this site so you should add some details specific to your implementation.

Comment: Using fewer draw calls by changing buffer data with something like `glBufferSubData` may actually hurt your performance more than help because GL is not allowed to make changes to your data before previous draw calls finish (and remember that the CPU and GPU run asynchronously). So you either force GL to stall and finish previous draw calls, or make a copy of your buffer so you can change it without affecting previous calls.